# Is it a way to use an instance group as a backend of internal LB as well as http LB

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-platform

When I selected a instance group for a internal lb which already used by http lb. I see this error.

[image: https://gyazo.com/32f4d5c973a77745fc4f48a7db90f355]

> This instance group is set Utilization by ***** (and 2 more). Select
>   another instance group.

Is it a way to avoid this error?

The instance group is a GKE cluster node pool. It has both external and internal service (for other GCE instanes).

Answer (score 0):

I also asked the same question to Cloud Services Support and I got an answer.

Regarding the document,
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/backend-service#restrictions_and_guidance

> Both backends must use the same balancing mode, either UTILIZATION or RATE.

Internal (TCP) LBs don't have balancing mode, so they cannot use a backend service which used by HTTP LB.

As a work around, I'll separate node pools. e.g. internal and external purposes.